# How to send Image data type via socket in java

Tags: java, image, sockets

I really confused how to send an Image data type via socket. Please help me. I've searced how to convert Image data type to char[] but the result was 0.

Comment: Why char[]? shouldn't it be a byte[]?

Comment: you can convert you image to byte Array and send that array to socket and convert byte Array to image onthe other side.

Comment: I think it can be send with char[] or byte[] isn't it right?

Comment: Image data type in Java of course. Like integer or char or String, etc.

Comment: `char[]` contain characters, `byte[]` contain bytes. Your image contains bytes, not characters.

Comment: Oh I see. But my question was how to covert Image data type that I got from camera to byte[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `Image` to `BufferedImage` with this method ([source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/380929/java/java/convert-Image-RenderedImage)):

```
public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(final Image image, final int type) {
    //Test if image does not need conversion
    if (image instanceof BufferedImage)
        return (BufferedImage) image;
    //Check if image can be converted easily
    if (image instanceof VolatileImage)
        return ((VolatileImage) image).getSnapshot();
    //loadImage method ensures that the image has loaded fully (it could be from the web or something). If you are sure that when this method is called - the image is loaded, you can remove this line and whole method.
    loadImage(image);
    //Create new BufferedImage with the same width and height and given data type (see constants in BufferedImage API)
    final BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), type);
    //Get graphics out of our new BufferedImage. Graphics2D is used to draw something on the image
    final Graphics2D g2 = buffImg.createGraphics();
    //Use Graphics2D to draw our Image contents on top of BufferedImage
    g2.drawImage(image, null, null);
    //We no longer need our graphics object as we drawn everything we wanted
    g2.dispose();
    //Return BufferedImage
    return buffImg;
}

//Method that ensures that the image was loaded succesfully
private void loadImage(final Image image) {
    //Inner class implementing the ImageObserver interface. It will be used to track the image loading progress
    class StatusObserver implements ImageObserver {
        boolean imageLoaded = false;
            //Each time an image updates - it will call this method
        public boolean imageUpdate(final Image img, final int infoflags, 
              final int x, final int y, final int width, final int height) {
                    //When flags contains ALLBITS flag - that means that the image was fully loaded.
            if (infoflags == ALLBITS) {
                synchronized (this) {
                                    //Therefore we set status to true
                    imageLoaded = true;
                                    //And notify anyone who was waiting for our job to be done
                    notify();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Then we create the observer itself
    final StatusObserver imageStatus = new StatusObserver();
    //We aquire it's monitor with this synchronized block. This will allow us to "wait" for it to complete loading (see notify() in StatusObserver)
    synchronized (imageStatus) {
            //Basically if image is loaded - it will have it's width and height set
        if (image.getWidth(imageStatus) == -1 || image.getHeight(imageStatus) == -1) {
                    //While status observer is not loaded
            while (!imageStatus.imageLoaded) {
                try {
                                    //We wait for status observer to notify us
                    imageStatus.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can write the resulting `BufferedImage` with [ImageIO.write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) method.

Comment: Help me to understand it max.:)

Comment: @ChristoforusSurjoputro There you go, I commented on each line of code.

Comment: Thank you so much max. You're so kind.:)

Comment: public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(final Image image, final int type) {
     if (image instanceof BufferedImage)
         return (BufferedImage) image;
     if (image instanceof VolatileImage)
         return ((VolatileImage) image).getSnapshot();
     final BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), type);
     return buffImg;
 }

I've a question. How the image converted to buffered Image? I didn't saw in that program which do that job. But it works perfectly.. Thank you..:)

Comment: @ChristoforusSurjoputro In my code, this part does the conversion part: `g2.drawImage(image, null, null);`. If your code works (the one in comment) - that means you are lucky and already have BufferedImage or VolatileImage.

Comment: Yes you're right. I just need (BufferedImage)Image. Thank you @Max.:)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) write method.

Comment: I've tried it, but ImageIo.write must be implemented with renderedimage like char[] or byte[]. I can't convert from Image to char[] or byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("image.png");
byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
int readData;
while((readData = inp.read(buffer))!=-1){
socketOutput.write(buffer,0,readData);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell you all that my image get from camera, not from a file. How I must doing with Image data type?

Comment: you can save the Image to a temporary file and transfer the file.